# How to detect a sequence of blinking lights in Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, sequence, led, light

While there are other examples that use the intensity to detect whether lights are blinking or not, I am in a position where I need to detect and LED that blinks a specific sequence of colours, i.e. red, green, green, red. The timing between each light is the same. This means that as some other threads have suggested using the timing between the lights to detect it can't be used.

Ideally this would be possible in Python and OpenCV, as I am using a raspberry Pi 4 to run this program.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe the keyword search you're looking for is "color threshold" or "color segmentation with `cv2.inRange`"

Comment: colour threshold is just to detect what colour is appearing, my problem is less with colour recognition, but rather how to communicate the order of colours seen and somehow make them relate to the presupposed sequences.

Comment: Yes you can use color thresholding to obtain a mask, then count the number of pixels on the mask, if it is above some threshold then the LED is on, if its below then its off. Depending on your color range, you can determine what color LED is on

Comment: I have a program that can detect red, green and blue in a live video frame, but I'm stuck on how to detect the actual sequencing order, and correlate that to a predetermined sequence. i.e the program can recognise that it has seen red red green and then tell me.